# powershell - mystery whitespace from output of loops

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am getting whitespace added to my output from the following section of code.  I need to format this a certain way so for sake of finding out where this whitespace is coming from I am just outputting the variables.  I even added `.trim()` to make sure it wasn't coming from the variables themselves.  Where in the heck is this whitespace coming from?

```
#sort by Name and sort Values of each
$output += foreach($icon in $table.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Name) {
    $icon.Name.trim()
    foreach($type in $icon.Value | sort) {
        $fa_types[$type].trim()
    }
}

#Output to file
"version: " + $fa_version + "`r`nicons:`r`n" + $output | Out-File $output_file
```

example output file :

```
version: 5.13.0
icons:
arrow-circle-right solid regular calendar-week regular users solid usb-drive solid file-alt regular key solid user-graduate solid comment-dots regular plus solid calendar-check regular spinner regular stopwatch regular file-search solid user-chart solid map-marker-alt regular calculator regular apple brands
```

Running powershell version 5 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a strange way to create a string... I recommend a safer way, where no output functions of PowerShell are involved:

```bsh
#sort by Name and sort Values of each
$output = ""
foreach($icon in $table.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Name) {
    $output += $icon.Name
    foreach($type in $icon.Value | sort) {
        $output += $fa_types[$type]
    }
}

#Output to file
"version: " + $fa_version + "`r`nicons:`r`n" + $output | Out-File $output_file
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I do prefer this way as it makes more sense looking at it what is happening rather than the output functions.  Still getting used to using powershell, but getting used to it as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Reason this is happening is because you are printing an array within a string. When you loop over your items and print just the `$fa_types[$type]`, it writes it as item of an array to the `$output`.

If you print only `$output`, you will see multiple items separated new line but if you put that inside of a string, its represented by a space delimiter.

Examples:

```
$outp = foreach($var in (0..5)) { $var }
$outp

# shows the following output
# 0
# 1 
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5

Write-Output "string  $outp  end"

# prints it in a single line
# string  0 1 2 3 4 5  end
```

You can concatenate your array via a join so no spaces are printed in your output.

```
"version: " + $fa_version + "`r`nicons:`r`n" + $output -join "" | Out-File $output_file
#or
"version: " + $fa_version + "`r`nicons:`r`n" + -join $output | Out-File $output_file
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on why it was actually happening.  I tried everything I could think of... like casting the variable out as string, trim, etc and couldn't understand where the space was coming from.